# Fetch small size image in Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-web-api, gzip

There will be images of size about `500kb to 1mb`.

And I will be saving them on the backend after compressing them (using `gzip`).

When i will make an API call, I will be fetching about `50 images` in one go.

Is there a way to fetch small size images like the size of an icon (Like whatsapp does for profile picture).

My main motive here is to compress the images `(to save memory)`,

and fetch small size image **(`TO SAVE FETCH TIME`).**

I though of saving two things, one is the compressed file and the other is low quality image, and then fetch them according to my needs.

Is this a good way, will the memory be compromised ?
Or is there a better way.

Comment: -Wich stack are you using , grpc / webapi , .net core ..... ? Your response can automaticaly be compressed : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-7.0
-JSON is not the best to exchange Byte data , you should diffinetly use streaming mode for your images take a look at this link : https://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/
-The best approch is to not send everything once, send chunk by chunk for low res pictures, then have another EndPoint for high resolution pictures.

Comment: Compression won't help with formats like JPG or PNG that are already compressed. You may end up *increasing* the file size. There are a lot of duplicate questions and answers that show how to create thumbnails